# How to get all the rows from a table

Tags: c#, linq

How is the best way to get all rows in a table with LINQ?

Upfront i have generated a *.dbml file and created a dbContext.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just reference the generated enumerable collection in the context class:

```
var allRecords = context.SomeTable;
```

Comment: So `DbClassDataContext myDb = new DbClassDataContext();
            var allRecords = myDb.FilmMedias;` will do the trick?

Comment: I have a small problem. The namsespace of my *.dbml is CatalogDb, while my class namespace is Catalog. Can i cast this in any way? CatalogDb.FilmMedia >< Catalog.FilmMedia

Answer (score 3):

Could be

```
FooDB fooBD = new FooDB();
var foo = fooBD.EntityFoo.ToList();
```

Comment: shouldnt 'db' be 'fooBD' ? so var foo = fooBD.EntityFoo.ToList(); ?